# C++ auto issue or my mistake ?!

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d10

Is auto universal and works with any API, or i am not using it correctly i guess should be work in this case but error, if i shall change it with concrete type will work, but why ?

```
//  Set  vertex  buffer
auto  stride = m_FullScreenVTFTonemapPass.stride;
auto  offset = m_FullScreenVTFTonemapPass.offset;
m_pD3DDevice->IASetInputLayout( m_FullScreenVTFTonemapPass.IALayout );
m_pD3DDevice->IASetVertexBuffers ( 0, 1, &m_FullScreenVTFTonemapPass.VBdata, &stride, &offset );
m_pD3DDevice->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP );
```

in  IASetVertexBuffers()  function  stride and  offset  should  be  referenced  but  errors  are  popping up  ,   if i'll  change one of them  stride or offset  with  UINT  it works  but  why  auto  does  not  work ?!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could tell us *what* "errors are popping up". In your editor? When building? When running? What is `m_FullScreenVTFTonemapPass.stride` and `m_FullScreenVTFTonemapPass.offset` supposed to be for types? What happens if you pass pointers to these members insteadof using the local variables?

Comment: @Achiko Mezvrishvili  It is obvious that there is some type inconsistence and the error message should point it out. So read the error message.

Comment: `IASetVertexBuffers` wants `UINT*` for both of those parameters, but (assuming `m_FullScreenVTFTonemapPass` is an instance of [PostFXFSQuad](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/63809468/), both those variables are of type `int`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter  Yeah my  mistake :).    IASetVertexBuffer()  needs  two UINT*  params not  simple  integers  and  auto returned  simple  integers  from PostFXQuad and IASetVertexBuffer() method was  throwing  error  about  casting  from simple  integer  to  UINT*  :). Thanks.

Comment: Omitting the exact error message you get is a disservice to the programming community. You know what people usually do first when they encounter a strange error message they don't understand? Copy and paste it into Google, hoping that a good Stackoverflow answer will pop up in the results. This obviously only works if the error message appears in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved  the issue was IASetVertexBuffer()  needs two UINT parameters  and  my  auto  declaration  was  getting two simple  integer(stride, offset)  that was an  error.  IASetVertexBuffer()  couldn't  cast  from  int to UINT* parameters.  That's it.

```
auto  stride = quad->stride;
auto  offset = quad->offset;
m_pD3DDevice->IASetInputLayout( quad->IALayout );
m_pD3DDevice->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &quad->VBdata, (UINT*)&stride, (UINT*)&offset);
m_pD3DDevice->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP );
```

P.S.  Anyway  if i will insist  to use  auto  then i will  cast  those  values stride  and  offset  with (UINT*)  and that's  it. Works  without  a  problem.

Comment: Using `auto` in this case seems pointless; why not just do `UINT stride = quad->stride;` instead?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I think  actually  auto in  general  in C++ is pointless and in  Win API,  this is my  personal opinion. In C#(CSHARP) var  works  best but in  C++  it is a better  to  declare  specific  type exactly  , either  way in Win api  u have to do  a lot of casting sometimes.  in C++  auto is  handy  when u exactly  know  what kind of  value  u will get  though.

Comment: auto is very useful for some things, e.g. iterators.

Comment: Might be in STL  when you  are iterating  through  containers.(map, vector etc).

Comment: At least go with ``reinterpret_cast<UINT*>(&stride), reinterpret_cast<UINT*>(&offset));`` I'm generally a fan of ``auto``, but I think in this case you are not using it well because your data structure has scalar values while the API expects to take an array. In this case ``UINT strides[1] = { quad->stride }; UINT offsets[] = { quad->offset };`` is probably clearer and more correct.

Comment: FWIW, I'd probably go with: ``auto  stride = static_cast<UINT>(quad->stride);
auto  offset = static_cast<UINT>(quad->offset);`` In general I like ``auto`` anywhere you basically have the same information on the LHS and RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Use auto for iterators and loops only. In my opinion using auto is a bad habit.

If you'll visit your code days or weeks later, you will hate yourself for using auto at every possible variable. And if there is a other coder who have to read your code try to avoid it completely.

In your special case? What do you thing will be better when using auto here? UINT and auto has both 4 letters, so lazyness can't be the reason. If you're looking at your code and you see a UINT you will immediatly know what type the variable is.

Comment: ``auto`` is IMO most useful anywhere the type is already explicitly listed such as cast statements; ``auto p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(data);``. It's also very useful where the specific type isn't critical and use is obvious by context: ``auto device = m_deviceResources->GetDirect3DDevice();  device->IASetInputLayout(...);``. Most of the crazy uses of ``auto`` are there only for the Standard Library and template metaprogramming...

Answer (score -1):

*auto* is not a *type definition* but a *storage class* (like *static*).

The compiler complains because you have told it *how and where* (in this case, on the stack) to store something, but not what the **something** should be.

You should add the type definition after the *auto* keyword, or as *auto* is the default anyways, *replace it* with the proper type.

```
UNIT stride = ......
```

Comment: hm :).   if  i will  use  type definition UINT  stride.......  what is the reason  of  auto ?  :)

Comment: The auto keyword declares a variable whose type is deduced from the initialization expression in its declaration.

Comment: For the past 5 years, `auto` has in fact indicated a (deduced) type. Being pedantic about it because he didn't specify the C++11 tag is unhelpful.